# Maintenance Type Dialog not showing

Tags: dialog, wix

I am developing an MSI with Custom UI dialogs. It has two features. When running the MSI installer first time, I am selecting one of the features and installing it. I want to run the installer again to install the second feature. I know that in the normal case, it would show the Maintenance Dialog with Change / Repair / Remove buttons from which I can select the Change option and install the other feature. But, since I am using Custom Dialogs including the Welcome Dialog, when I run it the second time, it directly goes from the Welcome Dialog to Progress Dialog to Finish dialog without even waiting / prompting for clicks. I do have a condition like below to navigate to MaintenanceTypeDlg from CustWelcomeDlg if the MSI is already installed once, but still no luck (Custom Welcome Dialog will have to navigate to the Custom License Agreement dialog if not already installed and will have to navigate to Maintenance Type Dialog if it is installed (even if one feature). Can anyone please help me? Note: Maintenance Type Dialog is out of the box, though I would like to customize that also later, since I want to customize the click event of Change button

```
<Publish Dialog="CustWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustLicenseAgmtDlg" Order="1">NOT Installed AND NOT PATCH</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="CustWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Order="2">Installed AND NOT PATCH</Publish>
```

Answer (score 0):

Me too have created custom setup using wix. For customized dialog and their sequence I referred to the WixUI_Advanced.wxs. The source code of the same is available on github. It may help you too. 
[Click here](https://github.com/AnalogJ/Wix3.6Toolset/blob/master/RC0-source/wix36-sources/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/WixUI_Advanced.wxs) to go to source code of WixUI_Advanced.wxs